# "DECLARE" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting: ERROR

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I tried every way possible to put the "DECLARE" in my procedural SQL query (Using MySQL Workbench) and its showing:

> "DECLARE" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting: ERROR.

Now I need help.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE getdetails()
BEGIN 
    DECLARE 
        vin table.vin%type; 
        responsetime table.responseTimeStamp%type;
        odometer table.odometer%type;
        chargePercentage table.soc%type;
        CURSOR sequential_vehicle_status is
                SELECT vin, responseTimeStamp, odometer, soc FROM table ORDER BY vin, responseTimeStamp;
    OPEN sequential_vehicle_status;
    LOOP
    FETCH sequential_vehicle_status into vin, responseTimeStamp, odometer, chargePercentage;
        EXIT WHEN sequential_vehicle_status%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line(vin || " * " || responseTimeStamp || " * " || odometer || " * " || chargePercentage || "% " ||);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE sequential_vehicle_status;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Sql server i think

Comment: it was fast bro, i mean the reply

Comment: Yeah than its mysql, I am new

Comment: yeah removed sorry for that

Comment: But plsql is for Oracle? Which is a completely different RDBMS?

Comment: Dbms_output is package in oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work. [Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e312931738e302993c17da230cc084a2). Please adjust the declared variables to your table column types.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getdetails()
BEGIN

DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0; --this is added so the exit from loop can be made

DECLARE vin int; 
DECLARE responseTimeStamp int;
DECLARE odometer int;
DECLARE chargePercentage int;
DECLARE sequential_vehicle_status 
cursor for
    SELECT vin
           , responseTimeStamp
           , odometer
           , soc 
    FROM `table` 
    ORDER BY vin, responseTimeStamp;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
    FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;--this is added so the exit from loop can be made

OPEN sequential_vehicle_status;
start_loop: LOOP

IF finished = 1 THEN 
        LEAVE start_loop;
    END IF;

FETCH sequential_vehicle_status into vin
                                     , responseTimeStamp
                                     , odometer
                                     , chargePercentage;

select concat(vin, '*', responseTimeStamp, '*', odometer, '*', chargePercentage, '% ');                                         

END LOOP;
CLOSE sequential_vehicle_status;
```

END;

Please read the comments to your question. **DBMS_OUTPUT is oracle package.**
Instead of that dbms_output line of code you can add this:

```
select concat(vin, '*', responseTimeStamp, '*', odometer, '*', chargePercentage, '% ');
```

Comment: Yeah you were right, i just mixed things up. but one problem, why the select statement poping new output window for every iteration. Couldnt i show those in single output table? and i think concate dont work when there is null. BTW thank for you knowledge.

Comment: I am happy to help. You are welcome. I am not sure what do you mean when you say "poping new output window" , you are looping through data, and you will write the result of every iteration. And welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I suggest to you to open a new question with that problem. Also , please do try to be better when you write the question. Give as much details you can and be as clear as possibly can. It is showing the respect to the ones that will help you. And when the question is great you will see that you will get more great answers... Cheers!

Comment: Yeah thank you. Sorry if it was pain to figure out the question. But still you gave a lot of detail that i was doing wrong. And about the output windows, I sorted that problem by creating a temp table and than used to display the result using that table otherwise it was showing multi tab output in mysql workbench as single row. that is if the row number is 100. 100 output tabs with 1 row.

Answer (score -1):

You are combining mysql and oracle syntax both.
Dbms_output is package in oracle and IS clause is used in oracle to create cursor.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE getdetails()
        BEGIN 
            DECLARE vin table.vin%type; 
            DECLARE responsetime table.responseTimeStamp%type;
            DECLARE odometer table.odometer%type;
            DECLARE chargePercentage table.soc%type;
            DECLARE CURSOR sequential_vehicle_status for 
                        SELECT vin, responseTimeStamp, odometer, soc FROM table ORDER BY vin, responseTimeStamp;
```

Also if you want to print something to console use select instead dbms_output which is oracle package.

ie. `SELECT concat('VIN is ', vin);`

Comment: Now the same error poping up for "IS" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting: ERROR

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getdetails
IS
BEGIN
 DECLARE

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getdetails
IS
BEGIN
 NOw the problem is with "OR"

Comment: not valid + SERVER, AGGREGATE, ALGORITHM new words in the error

Comment: You are combining two different syntax in one.